# pulling type of transaction out of transaction log

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe, bigdata

I have a problem, the data is from a related database but the function to recognize the type of transaction (A-only, B-only or A&B) wasn't build in.

I'm working in R in a non related structure. 
The transaction log is a log with articles(which have Maingroups) and also there is a line for payment type(left blank). Depending on the Maingroup it is a A or B observation.

I've made written a small part of code to check out. My question I want to get out of this a set that tells me:

- transaction 1 is A-only
- transaction 2 is B-only
- transaction 3 is A&B
- transaction 4 is A&B

I have to do this on a dataset of roughly 16 million observations.

```
trans.log <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4)
trans.log <- as.data.frame(trans.log)
trans.log$Maingroup <-c(1,1, "", 2, 4, "", 3, 1, 4, "", 1, 2, "")
trans.log[(trans.log$Maingroup %in% 1), "AorB"] <- "A"
trans.log[(trans.log$Maingroup %in% 2), "AorB"] <- "B"
trans.log[(trans.log$Maingroup %in% 3), "AorB"] <- "B"
trans.log[(trans.log$Maingroup %in% 4), "AorB"] <- "B"
trans.log[(trans.log$Maingroup %in% 6), "AorB"] <- "B"
trans.log[(trans.log$Maingroup %in% 7), "AorB"] <- "B"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After last night I've found my own awnser.

```
trans.log1 <- trans.log %>% group_by(JournalHeaderId, AorB)
%>% summarise(aantal=n())

# nieuwe kolommen maken voor  de aantallen A / B per transactie
trans.log2 <- trans.log1 %>% spread(AorB, value = aantal)

# nieuwe kolommen maken voor als B is NA of F is NA 
trans.log3 <- trans.log2 %>% mutate(Bonly=(B>= 1 & is.na(A)),
                    Aonly=(A>=1 & is.na(B)), AB=(B>=1 & A>=1), 
                    NonX=(NX>=1), other = (is.na(B) & is.na(A) & is.na(NX)))
```